# Can't contact LDAP server on ldap_bind($con, $rdn, $pwd)

Tags: php, zend-framework, active-directory, ldap

for a while now i'm fiddling around with an LDAP connection to an Active Directory Server for authentication. I tried this the PHP native way and also using Zend Framework. Even though the `ldap_connect()` works fine, as soon as i bind something, the ldapConnection appears to break down. This is the script i've tried

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
putenv('LDAPTLS_REQCERT=never');

$ldapcon = ldap_connect("FQSN", 636);

ldap_set_option($ldapcon, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ldapcon, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

$anon = ldap_bind($ldapcon, "CN=WebTestuserAW,OU=Benutzer,OU=DOM,DC=dom,DC=de", "Sommer2012");
//also tried: 
//$anon = ldap_bind($ldapcon, 'WebTestuserAW@dom.de', 'Sommer2012');

echo ldap_error($ldapcon);
```

Using the above i get **Can't contact LDAP server**. Doing a `var_dump($ldapcon)` returns a resource link. When trying to connect using the Zend Framework approach, the error may have some more hints, since some additional connection parameters are given

```
2012-11-12T14:37:39+01:00 DEBUG (7): Ldap: 1: host=FQHN,port=636,bindRequiresDn=1,baseDn=OU=Benutzer,OU=DOM,DC=dom,DC=de,accountFilterFormat=(sAMAccountName=%s),useSsl=1,useStartTls=,accountDomainName=dom.de,username=CN=WebTestuserAW,password=*****
2012-11-12T14:37:39+01:00 DEBUG (7): Ldap: 2: /var/www/html/login/library/Zend/Ldap.php(850): 0x1: Failed to retrieve DN for account: stosic@dvv.de [0x51 (Can't contact LDAP server): ldaps://FGHN:636]
2012-11-12T14:37:39+01:00 DEBUG (7): Ldap: 3: #0 /var/www/html/login/library/Zend/Auth/Adapter/Ldap.php(316): Zend_Ldap->bind('username@dom.de', '*****')
```

I seriously just have no clue anymore. I've googled around, played a bit with LDAP-Protocol Versions, played around with the request certificate option, but simply nothing helps. The connection to the server works per se on `ldap_connect` but as soon as you bind something it doesn't work anymore. This remains true for anonymous binds, too.

At office no one has any clue and neither do i. So if anyone has any suggestions on what i can still try, i'd be very greatful for that! Thanks in advance.

Additional information:

- Server LDAP Config:

  - LDAP Support enabled
  - RCS Version  $Id: ldap.c 299434 2010-05-17 20:09:42Z pajoye $
  - Total Links  0/unlimited
  - API Version  3001
  - Vendor Name  OpenLDAP
  - Vendor Version   20343
  - SASL Support Enabled
- Both ldap:// and ldaps:// has been tested
- ldap_connect() returns a resource link
- ldap_bind() doesn't work, ldap_errno() returns -1 (Can't connect to LDAP Server)
- LDAPTLS_REQCERT and TLS_REQCERT

Comment: Urg, I've had this before but not in *years*. Not really an answer, but IIRC I think I had a problem just like that because of the ldap module itself not working (i.e. wasn't built properly). Might be worth quickly trying on another platform if that's possible.

Comment: @Sam can you post the contents of your /etc/ldap.conf file also?

Comment: @dearlbry "There is no ldap.conf" - ©server-guys :) Can you be more precise what exactly you need?

Comment: @Sam I mean on the client - on the box that the script is running from. From the logs you posted, it looks like a Linux webserver - there should be a file called /etc/ldap.conf. And in there, you need to set "TLS_REQCERT never".

Comment: @dearlbry It is a linux, yes, but sysadmins tell me there's no ldap.conf. I've set the TLS_REQCERT=never via `putenv()`, too. Didn't change anything. My current assumption is that despite their call, the connection between servers isn't set up correctly. Will taka a couple of days to get that sorted out though... Thanks a lot for your help, still, i appreciate it a lot!

Comment: @Sam Well the ldap.conf file could be somewhere else (like /etc/openldap/ldap.conf), and I'd be surprised if there wasn't one. You can always create it if it's really missing. You could get the sysadmins to try the [steps outlined here](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Active_Directory_Authentication_using_LDAP#LDAP_client_.28.2Fetc.2Fopenldap.2Fldap.conf.29) to ensure the webserver can connect to AD. Could be an SElinux issue too come to think of it. Good luck!

Comment: @dearlbry Good catch, that sounds oddly familiar too...

Answer (score 2):

By default, ldaps is not enabled in AD. Did you try connecting over port 389? Are you able to connect to it using some LDAP tool (like [Apache Directory Studio](http://directory.apache.org/studio/))?

That's my guess as to why it's not working... but try using the FQDN of the DC too, or maybe even an IP.

Comment: Connection without ldapS resulted in the same error on bind. The full RDN was actually taken outside of Softerra LDAP Browser, so that should be working, but tomorrow at work i will try using FQDN on DC, too. Really hard to debug to me, it's a Dev-Webserver and all the Serverguys can tell me is "connection from A to B is working" :S

Comment: Connecting on port 636 isn't likely to work unless you have done a bunch of modification to your AD infrastructure (which isn't necessary for normal AD operation, so it likely hasn't happened).  So it makes sense to me that a bind on port 636 wouldn't work.  AD isn't likely to be listening on port 636.  I agree that you should try connecting on port 389.

Comment: As mentioned in my previous comment, port 389 doesn't work either, the error remains the same. Yet what i'm reading out of your comments is that most likely this is a configuration issue with the AD itself. Gotta double check with those admins then. Thanks so far!

Comment: Assuming you're on a linux box, I seem to remember needing to set "TLS_REQCERT never" in /etc/ldap.conf - might point you in the right direction at least: http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Active_Directory_Authentication_using_LDAP#LDAP_client_.28.2Fetc.2Fopenldap.2Fldap.conf.29

Comment: Thanks for the hint, this is done, too, at the top of my PHP File, as this was an error authenticating against edirectory, too. The error right now only is: as soon as i BIND something, i get no connection. The establishment of the link per se works. Binding doesn't

Comment: I see LDAPTLS_REQCERT in your code, but you might still need to set TLS_REQCERT never in your ldap.conf file - is that done? (try restarting apache afterwards) I still don't think you're *actually* connecting, because the connection doesn't happen until you bind - you always get a resource with ldap_connect() (see "Return Values" section at http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-connect.php)

Comment: Grr, for some reason SO doesn't notify me on new comments. Thanks for that hint again, i will most certainly check this. Additionally your comment about the connection to ldap only happening on a bind is very helpful, too! I will check into that.

Comment: i've added the ldap php configuration into my post. OpenLdap Vend version is 20xxx, so i guess this matches your previous comment about the connection not actually happening on ldap_connect(), back to the server guys :) Thanks a lot already!